# Dynamic parsing of xml with xslt

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I would like some help parsing a dynamic (folder.subfolders) xml with xslt, I tried a few things but I'm not there yet. Here is the structure of the xml that I have:

```
<FOLDERS>
    <FOLDER>
      <FOLDERID>2edfb864-5693-4e7f-8f98-4ef6e032d8a5</FOLDERID>
      <NAME>bla</NAME>
      <FOLDERSIZE>33Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
      <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-07 11:11:02</LASTMODIFIED>
      <SUBFOLDERS />
      <FILES>
        <FILE>
          <FILEID>1825</FILEID>
          <NAME>IMG_15052012_142711.png</NAME>
          <SIZE>33Kb</SIZE>
          <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
          <LASTMODIFIED />
        </FILE>
      </FILES>
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER>
      <FOLDERID>c9c5e2b2-ee93-49a2-b8be-d86e41528071</FOLDERID>
      <NAME>TestFolder</NAME>
      <FOLDERSIZE>0Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
      <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-05 00:00:00</LASTMODIFIED>
      <SUBFOLDERS>
        <FOLDER>
          <FOLDERID>3b43fe58-db85-43e6-b541-77ce250afc78</FOLDERID>
          <NAME>SubFolder</NAME>
          <FOLDERSIZE>362Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
          <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-05 00:00:00</LASTMODIFIED>
          <SUBFOLDERS>
            <FOLDER>
              <FOLDERID>ac1d35d0-80fd-4d97-8101-4de408f24dbd</FOLDERID>
              <NAME>subsub</NAME>
              <FOLDERSIZE>0Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
              <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-05 00:00:00</LASTMODIFIED>
              <SUBFOLDERS />
              <FILES />
            </FOLDER>
            <FOLDER>
              <FOLDERID>7cfdc199-9d0e-4f86-904d-eda3521f3e87</FOLDERID>
              <NAME>SUBSUB1</NAME>
              <FOLDERSIZE>0Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
              <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-05 00:00:00</LASTMODIFIED>
              <SUBFOLDERS />
              <FILES />
            </FOLDER>
          </SUBFOLDERS>
          <FILES>
            <FILE>
              <FILEID>1833</FILEID>
              <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
              <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
              <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
              <LASTMODIFIED />
            </FILE>
            <FILE>
              <FILEID>1834</FILEID>
              <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
              <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
              <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
              <LASTMODIFIED />
            </FILE>
            <FILE>
              <FILEID>1839</FILEID>
              <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
              <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
              <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
              <LASTMODIFIED />
            </FILE>
          </FILES>
        </FOLDER>
      </SUBFOLDERS>
      <FILES />
    </FOLDER>
    <FOLDER>
      <FOLDERID>1ead58e2-a412-4318-9629-d5c70d8681bc</FOLDERID>
      <NAME>TestFolder1</NAME>
      <FOLDERSIZE>241Kb</FOLDERSIZE>
      <LASTMODIFIED>2012-06-05 00:00:00</LASTMODIFIED>
      <SUBFOLDERS />
      <FILES>
        <FILE>
          <FILEID>1832</FILEID>
          <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
          <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
          <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
          <LASTMODIFIED />
        </FILE>
        <FILE>
          <FILEID>1837</FILEID>
          <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
          <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
          <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
          <LASTMODIFIED />
        </FILE>
      </FILES>
    </FOLDER>
  </FOLDERS>
  <FILES>
    <FILE>
      <FILEID>1836</FILEID>
      <NAME>Untitled.png</NAME>
      <SIZE>121Kb</SIZE>
      <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
      <LASTMODIFIED />
    </FILE>
    <FILE>
      <FILEID>1869</FILEID>
      <NAME>WallPaper.png</NAME>
      <SIZE>7.1Mb</SIZE>
      <EXTENSION>png</EXTENSION>
      <LASTMODIFIED />
    </FILE>
  </FILES>
```

The thing is that I don't know how deep the folders/subfolders tree can be.
I did already something but it is still static, it needs to be dynamic also, especially the select part if the xslt condition.

What do you guys think the best approach to parse the xml in this case?

This is the structure I would like to have:

```
Folders
     Subfolders       
          Subfolders 
               Subfolders
               Files
          Files
     Files 
Files
```

And this is what I have now:

```
<xsl:variable name="folderRoot" select="$xml/ROOT/FOLDERS/FOLDER" />
<xsl:variable name="fileRoot" select="$xml/ROOT/FILES/FILE" />

//Loop through the root folder
<xsl:if test="count($folderRoot) &gt; 0">
  <xsl:call-template name="folder"/>
</xsl:if>

//Loop through the root files    
<xsl:if test="count($fileRoot) &gt; 0">
   <xsl:call-template name="files"/>
</xsl:if>

//files template
 <xsl:template name="files">
    <xsl:for-each select="$fileRoot">
      <tr>
        <td class="defaultIcon {EXTENSION}">
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="NAME" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

//Folder template
 <xsl:template name="folder">
    <xsl:for-each select="$folderRoot">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="/default/components/bestandsbeheer/images/folder.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>Map</td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="LASTMODIFIED" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <!--SUBFOLDER 1 -->
      <xsl:if test="count(SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER">
         <!--SUBFOLDER 2 -->
          <xsl:if test="count($folderRoot/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:for-each select="$folderRoot/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER">
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="count($folderRoot/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER/FILES) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:for-each select="$folderRoot/SUBFOLDERS/FOLDER/FILES">
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>

      //Files belong to a sub folder
      <xsl:if test="count(FILES) &gt; 0">
        <xsl:for-each select="FILES/FILE">

        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: What's your intended output? Are you outputting a revised XML structure or HTML? What have you tried so far?

Comment: thanks for taking a look, i added what i have so far, let me know if somethign is not clear.

Comment: What is the difference between your input XML format and your desired output format? They seem sort of the same - a nest of folders/files.

Comment: some how i need a dynamic parsing of this xml to generate the appropriate html, the HTML should be just a list of folders sub folders and files. the parsing i did is statis and i need to convert it to be in a dynamic way. may be also this approach is not a good one!! thanks again for the check, any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: This is hugely unclear. You really need to post your expected output for your sample input. Statements like "the HTML should be just a list of folders sub folders and files" does **not** clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? It's a skeleton structure but you get the idea.

http://www.xmlplayground.com/c848Vl

Comment: thanks a lot, your example and the tool you provide helped me a lot. u r da man

Comment: is there a way also to keep track of the odd and even in the css style? thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes - have a look into the XPath function `position()`. Using a condition which checks this, you can add a class where required. You can try it in the XMLP session I linked to - feel free to save and overwrite the session, it's for you.

Comment: thanks again, i manage to fix that one. My last issue and sorry for that is that: how to hide the subfolders and sub files and when i click on a folder than i should see just this forlder and its content. i added something like this: <xsl:attribute name="style">display:block;</xsl:attribute> before <xsl:apply-templates select='$children' /> but still i'm not seeing amy changes. thanks a lot.

Comment: I've understood right, it would be a case of adding `display: none` to the children UL. If you need a ready-made HTML tree for this sort of thing, with expand/collapse nodes etc, you might want to use something like [my XMLTree plugin](http://www.mitya.co.uk/scripts/xmltree-186).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what output you want, but you need to learn how to use xsl:apply-templates, which is perfectly suited to processing this kind of recursive data using a recursive descent. I would expect your stylesheet to contain template rules that do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="FOLDER">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FILES"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="SUBFOLDERS"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FILES">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FILE"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SUBFOLDERS">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="FOLDER"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try to avoid xsl:for-each and xsl:if. They have a valid role to play, but don't use them until you have tried it first with template rules and match patterns: that's the XSLT way, and it's for this kind of structure that it really makes a difference.

Comment: thanks for taking a look, the output i'm looking for is just a list of folders, subfolders and files that belong to the subfolders or to the parent folder. your structure is very nice and clean but can u put me in any direction how to implement it? some examples?  thanks again.

Comment: how can i integrate your solution in my code? or i have to rewrite it? thanks